# Create line charts conditional on string variable

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

First of all, I'm very new to Python but alongside of doing different courses I also try to work with some "real" data.

I've got a DataFrame that is structured similar to this one:

```
data.head(10).to_dict()
Out[48]: 
{'Date': {0: Timestamp('2021-01-01 00:00:00'),
  1: Timestamp('2021-01-01 00:00:00'),
  2: Timestamp('2021-01-01 00:00:00'),
  3: Timestamp('2021-02-01 00:00:00'),
  4: Timestamp('2021-02-01 00:00:00'),
  5: Timestamp('2021-02-01 00:00:00'),
  6: Timestamp('2021-03-01 00:00:00'),
  7: Timestamp('2021-03-01 00:00:00'),
  8: Timestamp('2021-03-01 00:00:00'),
  9: Timestamp('2021-04-01 00:00:00')},
 'Share': {0: 'nflx',
  1: 'aapl',
  2: 'amzn',
  3: 'nflx',
  4: 'aapl',
  5: 'amzn',
  6: 'nflx',
  7: 'aapl',
  8: 'amzn',
  9: 'nflx'},
 'Share_price': {0: 534,
  1: 126,
  2: 3270,
  3: 590,
  4: 172,
  5: 3059,
  6: 552,
  7: 160,
  8: 3462,
  9: 535},
 'VX': {0: 147,
  1: 79,
  2: 137,
  3: 102,
  4: 157,
  5: 143,
  6: 177,
  7: 74,
  8: 72,
  9: 134}}
```

The only difference is that I got way more observations in terms of both "Share"(strings), periods and more variables.

The thing is that I want to create line charts of, in this data example, share price development and Vx from 2021-01 to 2021-04 for these three stocks in a single chart for resp. variable. I've tried really hard searching for answers but I have not found any. A guess from my side is that my data is not structured in a "python-friendly" way cause examples of such charts I find have data structured in like v1="Share_price_aapl", v2="Share_price_amzn" etc. But that would result in 300+ variables but maybe that's how I'm supposed to structure it? In that case, however, I would appreciate help in how to restructure the data in that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simple to do using e.g. the [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/index.html) library (which you may need to install first). Assuming that `data` is your dataframe you can plot values of the `'VX'` column against the dates as follows:

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.relplot(data=data,   # dataframe
            x='Date',    # column of x-values
            y='VX',      # column of y-values
            hue='Share', # different line colors depending on 'Share' column values
            kind='line', # get a line plot
            height=5,    # set the height of the plot
            aspect=2);   # the plot width will be 2 times its height
```

It gives:

[image: line plot]

You can customize this plot to suit your needs.

[Plotly Express](https://plotly.com/python/plotly-express/) provides similar features, but it produces interactive plots that can be zoomed, panned etc:

```
import plotly.express as px

fig = px.line(data_frame=data, x="Date", y="VX", color="Share")
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot! Is it possible to include more colors in the plots? As my data include a couple of more categories than it seems to be colors in both sns and px.

Comment: `sns.relplot()` has a `palette` argument that can be used to specify a list of colors. `px.line()` has `color_discrete_sequence` and `color_discrete_map` arguments which serve an analogous purpose.